# Change Azure encoding for PostgreSQL to SQL_ASCII

Tags: postgresql, azure

I need to create a database with the `SQL_ASCII` encoding on my [Azure PostgreSQL server](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/services/postgresql/#overview), however, it doesn't allow me to.

Here is the SQL I attempt to execute:

```
CREATE DATABASE sipis OWNER sipis ENCODING 'SQL_ASCII' LC_COLLATE 'C' LC_CTYPE 'C';
```

And I get the following errors:

```
[2021-08-09 20:01:44] [22023] ERROR: new encoding (SQL_ASCII) is incompatible with the encoding of the template database (UTF8)
[2021-08-09 20:01:44] Hint: Use the same encoding as in the template database, or use template0 as template.
```

I have tried changing the `client_encoding` on the Azure portal to no avail (it still results in the exact same error).

Is this even possible? The following is how it can be done on a local server installed with PostgreSQL:

```
UPDATE pg_database SET datistemplate = FALSE WHERE datname = 'template1';
DROP DATABASE template1;
CREATE DATABASE template1 WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = 'SQL_ASCII' LC_COLLATE 'C' LC_CTYPE 'C';
UPDATE pg_database SET datistemplate = TRUE WHERE datname = 'template1';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried just doing what the HINT says?

```
CREATE DATABASE sipis OWNER sipis ENCODING 'SQL_ASCII' LC_COLLATE 'C' LC_CTYPE 'C' TEMPLATE template0;
```